# What is happening to my files when they're moved in a bamboo stage?

Tags: bamboo

Total bamboo noob here: I have a gulp command in my client directory that takes the built application files relevant to serving up the client and copies those files into the appropriate resource directories for each platform's server that I'm building.

This works serially when I run it from command-line but I'm trying to understand how this fits in with Bamboo's stages.

Right now my stages look like this

[image]

Where my client has the following tasks:

[image]

Most of this is just invoking separate gulp commands and examining the output. But my issue is that the gulp command that moves the client files to the server asset folders is not persisted between the stages.

Once my bamboo server reaches the server stage, the folder no longer exists?

Comment: I'm thinking what I need to do is take the `client/build` directory that I'm creating and then moving the files from and instead share it as an artifact and from my other stage set it as a required artifact dependency and specify the appropriate directory that it should be accessible from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My earlier comment above on the original post was almost exactly what I needed to do. Bamboo only supports the ant file-copy pattern which doesn't have an exclusion we can use in the glob pattern (as it's not regex) so I had to change my build around a little bit to contain multiple folders, one for the platform agnostic client files and another for the specific platform client files but this allowed me to setup some artifact dependencies such that they could be included in my other stages after they're shared.

[image]